# Thin client that is only allowed to run certain applications

Tags: browser, ltsp

Im thinking about testing out LTSP on a PPC server for a handful of PPC macs. Before I go ahead with testing and building out everything, is it possible to limit what apps are ran on the thin client? Lets say I only want the thin client to be able to run a web browser and adobe reader, is that possible? Almost like an internet café.

I'm also open to other suggestions, maybe thin provisioning isn't the right track to head down if I want a really 'locked' down OS.

Comment: As for other suggestions, have a look at [Webconverger](http://webconverger.com/)

Comment: Search keyword: kiosk. (This question may even be a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, LTSP transforms the clients into just X terminals (i.e., not much more than a display with keyboard and mouse), any restriction would have to be enforced at the server, in exactly the same way you would limit local users.